# MS Teams: How to initiate a private chat/conversation to a user from a c# backend

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams, office365connectors

I currently try to send a private notification to a user.
What I currently have is a connected bot and connector in my MS Teams environment.

In my c# backend I have the bot which inherit from the ActivityHandler, the tenant id and the user id of ms teams.

The case is now:
Someone is creating an object (for example a Task) in my backend by making an API Post call and I want to notify the user in ms teams.
My idea was now to instantiate the Bot in my API controller (including the ITurnContext). Then with the bot find the right ms teams environment with the tenant id and user id, create a new chat/conversation and send the message. But I guess this is not the right way or I do something wrong. Because I think there is no way to initialise the ITurnContext from my code or?

This is my code and my idea was to use the CreatePrivateConversation method in my API controller.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Bot.Builder;
using Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Teams;
using Microsoft.Bot.Connector;
using Microsoft.Bot.Connector.Authentication;
using Microsoft.Bot.Schema;
using Microsoft.Bot.Schema.Teams;

namespace IntegrationsService.Bots
{
    public class ProactiveBot : ActivityHandler
    {
        double _secondsToReply = 3;
        ICredentialProvider _credentialProvider;

        public ProactiveBot(ICredentialProvider credentialProvider)
        {
            _credentialProvider = credentialProvider;
        }

        public async Task<ConversationResourceResponse> CreatePrivateConversation(string message, ITurnContext turnContext)
        {
            ConnectorClient _client = new ConnectorClient(
                new Uri(turnContext.Activity.ServiceUrl),
                await GetMicrosoftAppCredentialsAsync(turnContext),
                new HttpClient());
            var channelData = turnContext.Activity.GetChannelData<TeamsChannelData>();

            var conversationParameter = new ConversationParameters
            {
                Bot = turnContext.Activity.Recipient,
                Members = new[] { new ChannelAccount("userid") },
                // IsGroup = true,
                ChannelData = channelData,
                TenantId = channelData.Tenant.Id,
                Activity = MessageFactory.Text(message)
            };

            var response = await _client.Conversations.CreateConversationAsync(conversationParameter);
            return response;
        }

        protected override async Task OnMessageActivityAsync(ITurnContext<IMessageActivity> turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            try
            {
                await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Text($"I'll reply to you in {_secondsToReply} seconds."));
                QueueReplyAndSendItProactively(turnContext).Wait();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(e.Message);
                throw e;
            }
        }

        public async Task QueueReplyAndSendItProactively(ITurnContext turnContext)
        {
            string conversationMessage = "I created my own conversation.";
            string replyMessage = "I proactively replied to this conversation.";

            var task = Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(_secondsToReply));
                // Let the Bot Proactively create a a conversation.
                var response = await CreateConversation(conversationMessage, turnContext);

                // Reply to the conversation which the bot created.
                await ProactivelyReplyToConversation(response.Id, replyMessage, turnContext);

                return Task.CompletedTask;
            });
            await task;
        }
        public async Task<ConversationResourceResponse> CreateConversation(string message, ITurnContext turnContext)
        {
            ConnectorClient _client = new ConnectorClient(new Uri(turnContext.Activity.ServiceUrl), await GetMicrosoftAppCredentialsAsync(turnContext), new HttpClient());
            var channelData = turnContext.Activity.GetChannelData<TeamsChannelData>();

            var conversationParameter = new ConversationParameters
            {
                Bot = turnContext.Activity.Recipient,
                IsGroup = true,
                ChannelData = channelData,
                TenantId = channelData.Tenant.Id,
                Activity = MessageFactory.Text(message)
            };

            var response = await _client.Conversations.CreateConversationAsync(conversationParameter);
            return response;
        }

        public async Task ProactivelyReplyToConversation(string conversationId, string message, ITurnContext turnContext)
        {
            ConnectorClient _client = new ConnectorClient(new Uri(turnContext.Activity.ServiceUrl), await GetMicrosoftAppCredentialsAsync(turnContext), new HttpClient());
            var reply = MessageFactory.Text(message);
            reply.Conversation = new ConversationAccount(isGroup: true, id: conversationId);
            await _client.Conversations.SendToConversationAsync(reply);
        }

        private async Task<MicrosoftAppCredentials> GetMicrosoftAppCredentialsAsync(ITurnContext turnContext)
        {
            ClaimsIdentity claimsIdentity = turnContext.TurnState.Get<ClaimsIdentity>("BotIdentity");

            Claim botAppIdClaim = claimsIdentity.Claims?.SingleOrDefault(claim => claim.Type == AuthenticationConstants.AudienceClaim)
                ??
                claimsIdentity.Claims?.SingleOrDefault(claim => claim.Type == AuthenticationConstants.AppIdClaim);

            string appPassword = await _credentialProvider.GetAppPasswordAsync(botAppIdClaim.Value).ConfigureAwait(false);
            return new MicrosoftAppCredentials(botAppIdClaim.Value, appPassword);
        }

        protected override async Task OnMembersAddedAsync(IList<ChannelAccount> membersAdded, ITurnContext<IConversationUpdateActivity> turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            foreach (var member in membersAdded)
            {
                if (member.Id != turnContext.Activity.Recipient.Id)
                {
                    await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Text($"Hello and Welcome!"), cancellationToken);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Please take a look at [Send proactive notifications to users](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-howto-proactive-message?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp) documentation. Please let us know if you are facing any issue.

Comment: Thanks, but with the ContinueConversationAsync function I send a message to the public teams channel. Then every user from this channel can see the message. But I want that only one user can see it. 

Also, what happen if it is my first interaction with a user? Then I don't have a conversation. So I need a way to initialise a conversation and then send the message.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to initialize the ITurnContext from code. 
So If you want to send a private proactive message to user, You need to follow below steps

1. "OnConversationUpdateActivityAsync" method will be called when user install bot. You can get required parameters like ConversationId, ServiceUrl from turnContext.Activity.From object. you can store these details in database when each user installs the bot.

   OnConversationUpdateActivityAsync(
           ITurnContext turnContext,
           CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2. When user makes an POST API call, you need to pass user id or AadID based on which you can query database and get user details which are needed to send proactive message. Now you can call "CreatePrivateConversation" method and send the proactive message